# SQL REGEXP - Find all users that contains string

Tags: sql, regex, mariadb

I have table users, and column profile which is text field :

```
profile_name = "John"
profile_town = "LA"
profile_company = "Company XTB s.r.o"
profile_email = "john@gmail.com"
```

Is it possible to write SQL query, to find all users which company contains certain string ? 
For example: SELECT * FROM users WHERE `profile` REGEXP 'profile_company = %XTB%'

I can query WHOLE COMPANY NAME with LIKE %string%, but when I search for certain string in company name it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm lost.  Why doesn't `LIKE` work?

Comment: Using Profile_company like '%XTB%' is enough.

Comment: Hi @Mike, please explain to us what does it mean when you write : "it doesn't work".

Comment: Because profile_company isn't column. I have column profile (text type) and profile_company is just text in it.

Comment: Hi @Mike, your question is very confusing. Please do show us more data and explain what does not work. Because as you can se on this link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1dbcba48aa3dd2810ade1da4240dc1f8 if you insert only one part of company name it does work fine. So, add more sample data, add expected results and add exact query(not this half query's you have already added) that does not work for you and explain why. You need to make more effort if you expect to get a quality help. So do that.

Comment: Either use JSON or split the text into columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
with xxx as (select 'profile_company = "Cmpany XTB s.r.o"' profile from DUAL)
select *
  from xxx
 where profile like '%profile_company%XTB%';
```